# Why does my method that I am trying to call to inside main not work?

Tags: java

`minGap(array);` is not being recognized. I don't know what I have done wrong, but I am sure it is a super simple fix. Trying to figure out if it is something to do with the data type being used or if it has something to do with the arrangement of the line " " added. Any hints?

```java
package Lab8;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question_One {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int length;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner to input any size array user wants

        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers for the array.");
        length = input.nextInt();

        String[] array = new String[length];

        for(int i = 0;i <length;i++) { //counter logic
                System.out.println("How many integers are in the array?"+(i+1));
                array[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers for the array (individually):");
        for(int i = 0;i <length;i++) { //counter logic
            System.out.print(array [i]);
            array[i] = input.nextLine();

        }

        input.close();

        minGap(array);

    }

    private static int minGap(int a[], int gapMin) {
        int []gap = new int[a.length];

        //a
        for (int i=0;i<a.length-2;i++) {
            if (gapMin>gap[i]) {
                    gapMin=gap[1];
            }


        }

        return gapMin;


    }

}
```

Comment: `private static int minGap(int a[], int gapMin) {` takes an `int[]` **and** an `int`. You need to pass `gapMin`. Or remove that from the signature. Why is it there?

Comment: I included the int gapMin in the signature to not have to have it be used for the entire method. I thought that it could be added here. After editing the code, I found that I named the variable incorrectly as minGap instead of gapMin. Not sure about how I am supposed to have gapMin(array); used for int data type when I used string before.

Comment: the point that @ElliottFrisch is making is that you call `minGap(String [])` but you define `minGap(int [], int)`;  those are *two different functions*, because their signatures are different -- only the *name* portion of their signatures is the same;  so the reason "minGap(array); is not being recognized" is because you have not defined `minGap(String []);` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted a method to *find* the minimum gap. As such, you should not be passing that *into* the method. Your logic is also a bit off, you want to take the minimum value after `gapMin>gap[i]` (not a hardcoded `gap[1]`). So you could do,

```
private static int minGap(int a[]) {
    int gapMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[] gap = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (gapMin > gap[i]) {
            gapMin = gap[i];
        }
    }
    return gapMin;
}
```

**or** (if you're using Java 8+)

```
private static int minGap(int a[]) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).min().getAsInt();
}
```

Then you need to actually save that value or `print` it. That is, change

```
minGap(array);
```

to (just print it)

```
System.out.println(minGap(array));
```

**And** you need an array of `int` (not a `String[]`).

```
int[] array = new int[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter integer %d for the array%n", i + 1);
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```